# Can't use markers with ASM in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, lnk2001

i need some help guys, i'm creating some vm and i'm using markers to define start point to protect and end point to protect.

So for example, when i try to do this, i get error:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "../Release/libphant.lib")

extern "C" {
    void __stdcall BeginProtect(unsigned int);
    void __stdcall EndProtect(unsigned int);
}

//BeginProtect(0xb1f12057)
//EndProtect(0x5720f1b1);
#define BeginProtect __asm {\
    __asm push 0xb1f12057\
    __asm call BeginProtect\
}
#define EndProtect __asm {\
    __asm push 0x5720f1b1\
    __asm call EndProtect\
}
```

So i'm getting :
unresolved external symbol"_BeginProtect@4" 
unresolved external symbol"_EndProtect@4"

What am i doing? 
I'm using asm lib file (as you can see)
and i'm Using markers BeginProtect and EndProtect in the main file.

Thank you!

UPDATED:
part from asm

```
public BeginProtect as "_BeginProtect@4"
public EndProtect as "_EndProtect@4"
```

main file i'm trying to build(just an example):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "phant.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>




using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    BeginProtect;


    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;



    EndProtect;

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: 
Thank you guys! i solved a problem. It's all about .lib file. it was corrupted a bit, i just recompilied it with FASM and builded wiht VS. and it's working just fine now!

Comment: How are you linking that assembly code?

Comment: i'm using linker

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What exact command do you use, what are the artifacts produced before?

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, "../Release/libphant.lib") thats what i'm using in C++ code. however BeginProtect and EndProtect feels ok in any other part of the Project ( i have a big project) , the problem just in this header. Maybe i need to define smth

Comment: Let me know what part do you need, it's hard to understand

Comment: It's just a markers, i do have parsers to get all info from it.

Comment: Since assembly language is processor specific, what processor are you targeting?

Comment: X86 only for now. Btw i have a problem in my main file(where i'm using BeginProtect and EndProtect) to protect code. And file i gave you is a header because of this file the problem occurs. I don't think it's asm problem.

Comment: i will try figure out it myself guys, i will try another windows/and projects, maybe i did some stupid error. because i used sdk for vm and it was working perfectly before.

Comment: The code in your question is just [a header file](https://github.com/ScalletaZ/phantasm-x86-virtualizer/blob/master/sdk_example/phant.h). Where is the real code you are trying to link?

Comment: added a part from asm (lib file) and the main file that giving error when i add BeginProtect and Endprotect

Comment: The symbols you are trying to link to must be exported by the library. On windows this is achieved by using declspec(dllexport) but I'm not sure how it works when compiling assembly. Look into how to export symbols.

Comment: but lib shouldn't send any symbols. because everything already described in header file(memory with lenght)

Comment: @paxxa Use `@username` when replying to people. Otherwise they might not get a notification and likely will never notice your reply. (*You're* getting notifications regardless because the comments are under your question.)